# Fragment の onCreateView() で、画面サイズが取得できない

Tags: android, java

Fragment の onCreateView()において、
画面サイズの取得をしようとしましたが、値は0を返します。
Fragment の画面サイズを取得するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_diet, container, false);
    float viewWidth = rootView.getWidth();
    float viewHeight = rootView.getHeight();
    Log.d("TestFragment", "横は" + viewWidth + ",縦は" + viewHeight);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ビューが幅と高さを得るためにはレイアウトがなされる必要があります。 onCreateView の中ではまだビューのインスタンスを作ったというだけの段階であり、レイアウトされてないので、幅も高さも 0 なのは仕方ないです。

フラグメントのビューが最初にレイアウトされるのは onResume の後になるので、フラグメント設置時に幅と高さを得る方法というのは、「別スレッドで取得できるまで待つ」くらいしか思いつきません。

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_diet, container, false);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while (rootView.getWidth() == 0 || rootView.getHeight() == 0) {
                if (++i > 300) {
                    // 時間切れ離脱
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    Log.d("TestFragment", "waiting...");
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            float viewWidth = rootView.getWidth();
            float viewHeight = rootView.getHeight();
            Log.d("TestFragment", "横は" + viewWidth + ", 縦は" + viewHeight);
        }
    }).start();
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

英語版のstackoverflowの引用ですが、私は以下の方法でやってます。
onCreateView()ですぐに値を確定する方法はありません。
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4406090/3741336